# Ionic 2 release migration -> provider error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I try to create a page component which includes a provider in it, the page is blank and this error is shown:
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BackgroundPicturePage: (LoadingController, AlertController, NavController, ?, TranslateService).

**Here are my files:**

app.module.ts:

```
import { User } from '../models/User';

......

providers: [
    User,
],
```

background-picture.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../../models/User';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'background-picture.html',
})
export class BackgroundPicturePage {
  constructor(
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
        public nav: NavController,
        public user: User,
        public translate: TranslateService
    ) {
    }
}
```

My system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:  
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.3.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

Comment: Is `User` a provider (do you have `@Injectable`) or just a typescript model? If it is just a model, then you cannot use it as a provider.

Comment: I think that your TranlateService module have to be in your app.module.ts under the providers array, if you inject it in your constructor like you did ...

Comment: @AbM Yes, the User has @Injectable() prefix to it.

Comment: @sami_analyst The TranslateService is the ng2-translate module, and here is how I initiate it:

  imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpModule,
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
   provide: TranslateLoader,
   useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, '/assets/i18n', '.json'),
   deps: [Http]
  }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],

Comment: I see, didnt know abaout that :)

Comment: same problem with version `2.0.0-rc.3`, anyone has a solution for this? I cannot seem to be able to use any custom provider, I am completely stuck